# How to change "deployment target version" on SSIS 2019?

Tags: ssis, visual-studio

I am experiencing the following errors when using the "Transfer SQL Server Objects" task in SSIS on Visual Studio 2019:

```
An exception occurred in SMO 
Value cannot be null. Parameter name: server
```

These errors have previously been described in SSIS 2017 and could apparently be solved by changing the deployment target version to 2016 as described in these links:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/SECURITY/en-US/6096339d-766b-45ab-9e97-e8b49812aaf5/object-transfer-error-an-exception-occurred-in-smo-value-cannot-be-null-parameter-name-server?forum=ssdt

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48145026/why-does-ssis-transfer-object-stage-return-smo-failure

So as directed in the linked pages, I opened the "Deployment Property Pages" window and looked in "Configuration Properties" for the "General" option, but it is not present, all that is present is "Configuration" and it does not have a "Deployment Target Version" option.

[image: image of Deployment Property Pages]

Is there any way I can change the Deployment Target Version (or any other ideas about how best to resolve this error) in SSIS 2019?

I've tried Google but can't find anything relevant!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Be sure to go to the *Project* properties, not the solution properties. See image below.

[image]